# Using Inner Join in FilterClause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am rewriting the synchronization in a old project, and I want to keep it as similar to the old code as possible.

The old code had SQL codes that are similar to the `FilterClause`. And until now it has been very simple to convert the old codes select expressions to the corresponding FilterClause. For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table_a WHERE num_id = @id
```

has been translated to:

```
...FilterClause = "num_id = @id";
```

However, now I have run into a problem...

The FilterClauses definition is *Gets or sets the SQL WHERE clause (without the WHERE keyword) that is used to filter the result set from the base table.*
But now my sql expression is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table_a
INNER JOIN 
(
 SELECT DISTINCT(num_id) 
 FROM dbo.link_table_ab
 WHERE link_table_ab.b_index = 5
) T2 ON table_a.num_id= T2.num_id
```

So the problem is that there is no WHERE in the primary query... What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement essentially the same logic using `IN` with a subquery in the `WHERE` clause.  Does this work for you?

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table_a
WHERE table_a.num_id IN (SELECT num_id
                         FROM dbo.link_table_ab
                         WHERE link_table_ab.b_index = 5
                        )
```

Comment: How much impact will that have on the speed?

Comment: @Markus . . . It should be remarkably similar to the join as it was originally framed.  Sometimes, `exists` is a bit faster than `in`, but that can depend on data and your system.

Comment: Will not the DISTINCT pose any problems?

Comment: @Markus . . . The `distinct` is needed in the `join` to prevent duplication of rows.  You cannot duplicate rows with an expression in the `where` clause, so it is unnecessary.